# AM Radio gets static when driving near PV arrays, but not FM

Tags: radio, amplitude-modulation

My school has PV arrays that act as shades in the parking lot. Whenever I'm within 10ft of them, I get overpowering, humming AM static, but the FM signal is clear as day. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter what you are driving next to. AM is more susceptible to noise. An AM transmitter is basically a filter with gain. If there is noise on that channel you are going to hear it.

FM has a carrier frequency, when you tune your radio with FM the radio in it 'locks on' to that frequency an only information around the carrier gets sent to your speaker. This is not as susceptible to noise.

PV arrays are probably noisy because of DC to DC inverters and poor EMI control and which could also be harmonics of them converting to AC which would be lower frequencies around AM also.

If you drive next to power lines you get more noise on AM when you are close to the poles (power lines don't have as much regulations as consumer devices as far as emissions go) but FM comes in clear.

Comment: The big difference between AM and FM is that inverter switching frequencies (today) are much closer to the AM band.

Answer (score 1):

EMI - Electromagnetic Interference.

The panels are almost certainly feeding into an inverter/battery-charger, which will likely be drawing current in sharp-edged PWM waveforms, because that's how inverters/battery-chargers work - glorified switch-mode power supplies.

The frequency & rise/fall-time & mark/space-ratio of the current waveform caused by the inverter/battery-charger will be creating EMI at certain frequencies; actually a series of frequencies in certain integer multiples of the base frequency of the PWM frequency.

Whether those frequencies correspond to certain stations on the AM band, or the FM band, or any of the hundreds of MHz between and around them, depends on the specifics of the frequency & rise/fall-time & mark/space ratio of the PWM waveform.

Answer (score 1):

There *might* be some EMI being generated by inverter circuits associated with the solar panels, but the main reason you lose the AM signals is the same reason you lose them under bridges and in parking garages — AM signals simply do not penetrate into/under metallic structures that have apertures significantly smaller than the signal's wavelength.

So what you are experiencing is probably a combination of severe signal loss accompanied by a rise in EMI. If the solar panels are grid-tied (possibly using microinverters), it makes sense that the EMI would be amplitude modulated at line frequency.

FM signals don't experience the same kind of attenuation in the first place, and the EMI at FM frequencies is probably a lot weaker.